# Why is there an Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory in my panda script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I just wanted to run this in jupyter notebook, I am asking because It seems that this happens even on big VMs. I am on a Computer with low ram, so I have tried to limit tasks and such. But there is an issue with my code. I am using pandas and pyhon3

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")

df = df.copy()[df['type']=="organic"]
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=Ture, inplace=True)
```

But I end up with the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-7a58db10f05e> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 df = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")
      4 
      5 df = df.copy()[df['type']=="organic"]

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         )
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    455 
    456     # Create the parser.
--> 457     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    458 
    459     if chunksize or iterator:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1133     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1134         if engine == "c":
-> 1135             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1136         else:
   1137             if engine == "python":

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1915         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1916 
-> 1917         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1918         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1919 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True was spelled Ture, and Have you done a restart of your computer? I would do that sometimes task manager won't kill all the task and flush them. 
`df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=True, inplace=True)`